# nginx: Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code

Tags: nginx

**SOLVED** (see my answer below)

When I added a new nginx config **edu.conf** in sites-available and sites-enabled, nginx just died.

I cant restart service and all sites wont work.

When I type `sudo nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/sites-available/edu.conf` or the same command on any other of my nginx configs it throws error:

```
nginx: [emerg] "upstream" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-available/edu.conf:1
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-available/edu.conf test failed
```

I already had nginx config that was identical to the **edu.conf**, I just changed the root folders and server name.

If I check for syntax errors on any of previous files that were completely fine it throws a error on first line on all of them. Even the default one.

```
sw@asd:/etc/nginx/sites-available$ sudo nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/sites-available/magento2.conf
nginx: [emerg] "upstream" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-available/magento2.conf:1
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-available/magento2.conf test failed
sw@asd:/etc/nginx/sites-available$ sudo nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-available/default:16
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-available/default test failed
```

Here is the **edu.conf** that I added:

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
           server unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;        
        #  Or TCP
        #  server  127.0.0.1:9000;
}
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name edu.dev;
        set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html/mg;
        set $MAGE_MODE developer;
        include /var/www/html/mg/nginx.conf.sample;
}
```

Comment: They are not complete configuration files. They are intended to be included into `nginx.conf`, within an `http {}` block.

Comment: I have one that is identical to it and it works completely fine with a magento 2 installation.

Comment: The file is fine, but you cannot specify it on the command line - it needs to be included from within `nginx.conf` which is how `nginx` usually starts up.

Comment: @RichardSmith I don't understand what I need to do. I had the default nginx conf, I added one for a magento 2 that is exactly like the one I am having problems now with and it worked completely fine, I didn't do anything else. I literally added the same file, but just renamed it and changed config so that it's for a different installation.

Comment: Configurations are usually included from symbolic links in the `sites-enabled` directory. Add a symlink from `sites-available` for your active configurations and remove any symlinks for configurations you no longer require.

Comment: @RichardSmith I already have that. The problem is that it says I have syntax error in every single nginx config file after I added edu.conf to sites-available and made a link to sites-enabled.

Comment: So what happens when you invoke `sudo nginx -T`?

Comment: @RichardSmith `nginx: [emerg] duplicate upstream "fastcgi_backend" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/magento2.conf:1` magento2.conf is the file I grabbed config from, but worked fine.

Comment: Each upstream needs a unique name - you are loading two configs at the moment, both using the same symbol for the upstream identifier.

Comment: Changed the upstream name and now all of the previous sites work and I can run `sudo service nginx restart`. But when I run `sudo nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/sites-available/edu.conf` or the same command for magento2.conf I still get `nginx: [emerg] "upstream" directive is not allowed here in FILE_PATH`

Comment: As I said - you can't use `-c /etc/nginx/sites-available/edu.conf` because `edu.conf` is not a complete configuration file - it is only part of a configuration file - so on its own it is syntactically invalid.

Comment: @RichardSmith what a complete one would look like then? Every config I have seen so far (for magento 2) is the same as my or just includes server {} block. It gets included in nginx.conf `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;` and then in the config includes this `include /var/www/html/magento2/nginx.conf.sample;`

Comment: See my [recent answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41766195/nginx-emerg-server-directive-is-not-allowed-here/41766811#41766811)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual config was working, the problem was in the Magento 2 config. I had to change `root $MAGE_ROOT/pub;` to `root $MAGE_ROOT;` in nginx.conf.sample that is located in Magento 2 root directory. Or I had to type URL like this `edu.dev/setup` instead of `edu.dev`.