# How to rewrite or proxy url in nginx?

Tags: nginx, docker

I am new in nginx. I want to rewrite

```
feature-1234.mydomain.com/xyz?foo=bar
```

to

```
docker-feature-1234:9000/xyz?foo=bar
```

with request parameters.

I use official nginx docker image. How should be my nginx.conf file?

EDIT: 'feature-1234' is a variable so:

```
feature-5678.mydomain.com
```

should serve as

```
docker-feature-5678:9000
```

Answer (score 0):

By combining answers, i found the solution.

https://serverfault.com/questions/388552/nginx-sub-domain-proxy-pass

[Docker Network Nginx Resolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35744650/docker-network-nginx-resolver)

[nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41766195/nginx-emerg-server-directive-is-not-allowed-here)

nginx.conf:

```
events {
}

http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~(.*).test.go;

    location / {
      if ($host ~* ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.test\.go$) {
        set $proxyhost docker-$1:9000;
      }

      resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;
      proxy_pass http://$proxyhost;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;

    }
  }
}
```

Thanks