# "http" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx-basic.conf:1

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm seeing the "http" directive not allowed error from the logs. I have mounted "nginx-basic.conf" file in "conf.d" folder as a config mount in Kubernetes.

**nginx-basic.conf-**

```
http {
  server {
    location / {
      proxy_pass 35.239.243.201:9200;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }
  }

}
```

I'm not sure what is wrong with this. Could someone help me with pointing it out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nginx: \[emerg\] "server" directive is not allowed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41766195/nginx-emerg-server-directive-is-not-allowed-here)

Answer (score 3):

You probably have another `http` directive in a base `nginx.conf` that includes everything under `/etc/nginx/conf.d`

For example (`nginx.conf`):

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        ...
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

You can try removing the `http` directive:

```
server {
  location / {
    proxy_pass 35.239.243.201:9200;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

Comment: That was the reason. Thank you!