# nginx "mail" & "stream" directive is not allowed in site-enabled/

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-module

I have a problem when I try to use the stream or mail directive with nginx.
I'm using nginx/1.16.1 & Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.
This is my nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1200;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log off;
                    #/var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error_website.log;
    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.websiteconf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.websiteconf;
}
```

And I want to use the "stream" directive in one of my site configs (test.streamconf)

```
stream {
            server {
                    listen 500 udp;
                   proxy_pass test.com:500;
            }
            server {
                    listen 4500 udp;
                    proxy_pass test.com:4500;
            }
}
```

But if I create a symlink for the sites-enabled folder and test my configuration with "sudo nginx -t", I get the following error message:

> nginx: [emerg] "stream" directive is not allowed here in
>   /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/test.streamconf:1
>   nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

The stream and mail module is already installed...
[image]

What do I wrong?

Comment: Look at the `include` directives in your `nginx.conf` file. You have written `stream { stream { server { ... } } }`. You have nested two `stream` directives. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41766195/nginx-emerg-server-directive-is-not-allowed-here/41766811#41766811) which relates to the `http` directive, but the same applies to the `stream` and `mail` directives, as all three are at the top block level.

Comment: Stefan, Did you installed stream and mail module as a sudo user or a normal user ? It might be you are not able to load modules as a sudo user.

Comment: @RichardSmith, I have adapted (removed the stream directive) in the nginx.conf, but without success.

Comment: @InderRSingh: What do you mean exactly? I have installed the nginx, with "sudo apt install nginx". I haven't installed the stream and mail module separate.

Answer (score 5):

Okay, now I get it. nginx loads the individual configurations nested.
I have now added the following alls root to nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1200;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log off;
                    #/var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/websiteerror.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml appl$

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.websiteconf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.websiteconf;
}


stream {
    access_log off;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/streamerror.log;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.streamconf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.streamconf;
}
```

And my "stream" config file now looks like this (I thought that I have to start with "stream" here too)...

```
server {
    listen  [::]:4500 ipv6only=off;
    listen  [::]:500 ipv6only=off;
    proxy_pass      server_name.com:$server_port;
    proxy_protocol  on;
}
```